# How to implement a binary search in java in bluej?

Tags: java

I have this but the method isn't showing up on the object created in bluej.
How can an do a binary search on an int array then output the found int?

```
public static int binarySearch(int a[], int element)
{
    int first = 0;
    int upto = a.length;

    while (first < upto) 
    {
        int mid = (first + upto) / 2;  // Compute mid point.
        if (element < a[mid]) 
        {
            upto = mid;                // repeat search in bottom half.
        } else if (element > a[mid]) 
            {
                first = mid + 1;       // Repeat search in top half.
            } 
                else 
                {
                    return mid;        // Found it. return position
                }
            }
     return -(first + 1);              // Failed to find key
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You made the method **static**. Therefore it most likely appears in the context menu of the **class** not of the **object**.

Answer (score 0):

If you always returned found the `int` you are looking for, you would just return `element` every time.  There would be no point doing a search.  This method returns the index of the elements or the negative of the place it is inserted.

BTW: This code example has an old bug in the

```
int mid = (first + upto) / 2
```

which should read

```
int mid = (first + upto) >>> 1;
```

as it does in `Arrays.binarySearch();`

Comment: Explanation: if (first + upto) overflow maximal integer and becomes negative.